# Scatter Highcharts responsive issue Yii2

Tags: highcharts, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, scatter, yii2-extension

I am using scatter chart in Yii2 using the following extension
https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts

For responsive I have passed parameters like this.

```
<?php 
use miloschuman\highcharts\Highcharts; 
echo Highcharts::widget([               
    'options' => [
          'responsive' => [
            'rules'=> [
                [
                    'condition'=>
                    [
                        'maxWidth' => 500,
                    ],
                    'chartOptions'=> [
                        'legend' => [
                            'enabled'=> true,
                            'align'=> 'center',
                            'verticalAlign'=> 'bottom',
                            'layout'=> 'horizontal',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ],                                
        ], 

    ]); 
?>
```

But its not working for mobile as well as tablet.Can any one have idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Bhavi Tanwani, Please check if the specified options are in the correct type. As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/95tybrnm/ your configuration works in basic Highcharts, so I suggest you to contact directly with authors of yii2.

Comment: @ppotaczek I want to change whole size of chart. like in mobile I wantto set chart;s height width say 270px * 300px and in tablest 500px* 400px etc

Comment: It is very simple, just set correct chart options in responsive configuration. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6s1yq2L3/